# ActionBarDrawerToggle doesn't understand appcompat attributes when used with non-appcompat Theme.Material

Tags: android

I'm on minSdk=21 and using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle. I want to disable the spinning animation, and I do it like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggleStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggleStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
</style>
```

This results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.TestActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
            at android.support.v7.app.DrawerArrowDrawable.<init>(DrawerArrowDrawable.java:69)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:469)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:222)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:150)
```

When I add this to the style:

```
<item name="color">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
```

(which is exactly copied over from the parent style Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle), the same problem occurs.

The problem goes away when I use:

```
<item name="color">?android:attr/colorControlNormal</item>
```

i.e. with the 'android:' prefix.

When I don't define a custom style at all, it all also works fine, but as I mentioned, I don't like the spinning icons.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the issue occurs only with the 'color' attribute, the other ones don't need to be explicitly overridden.

What is the problem? Is it because I am mixing the standard android attributes with the appcompat ones, and the drawer toggle class doesn't know how to read attributes without the 'android:' prefix in this case?

This whole appcompat stuff is very confusing, especially the styles.

Comment: why are you using **support library** if your `minSdkVersion` is **`21`**??

Comment: Because there are quite a lot of classes which are only available in support libraries: ViewPager, RecyclerView, DrawerLayout, and the ActionBarDrawerToggle, which is the topic of this question. I use all of the aforementioned ones and as far as I know, there is no other way.

Comment: `<item name="color">?android:attr/colorControlNormal</item>` works with backward versions too, you don't need to remove `android` namespace. I'm writing app w/ minSdk 9, I use `android:` namespace with `attr` and it works without any problem.

Comment: @Apurva: please read the question again, I'm not removing anything; rather, I must add something or else it explodes.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, which was fixed with the snippet bellow. Hope it helps you!

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat's actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <!-- The drawing color for the bars -->
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- Whether bars should rotate or not during transition -->
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
</style>
```

**Note:** Perhaps you should use `Theme.AppCompat` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as the parent style.